# Preparing Pitch statement for management company

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I am final year PhD student and going to my first job fair. I want to ask couple of things
1) I have been assigned a consultant company by the organizers of the job fair. My background is related to Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning. About the company:

> Team of seasoned professionals bring with them extensive global
>   experience, across a broad range of complex strategic projects,
>   ranging from civil infrastructure and IT systems, through to the
>   introduction into service of specialist military capability platforms.
>
> Outstanding team of security cleared project professionals are able to
>   readily assist with a broad array of project functions including;
>
> 1. Project and Program Management
> 2. Contract Management and Negotiations
> 3. Project Governance and Controls
> 4. Business Case Development
> 5. Project Auditing
> 6. Project Recovery
> 7. Scheduling
> 8. Cost Estimation
> 9. Procurement Management
>      10.Tender Development and Evaluation

How can I prepare my pitch statement for this?

Comment: What does "assigned" mean?

Comment: The organizer of the job fair have assigned a time slot to me to have meeting with a consultant company

Comment: Without naming the company here, are you told who the company are? Or are you just given the above to work off?

Comment: Well i didnt feel to write the name  of the company. Thats why i wrote what they mainly do. If its important to write the name of the company, Please do let me know i will do that. They surely have told me that company name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the name of the company, you can research some of the projects they may have worked on, and see how those projects align with your interests and capabilities.

They are not likely to care about any theory that you have accumulated over the years, they want to understand how hiring you can give them a practical benefit with their projects.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have checked that but I couldn't found any completed project except "what they do", which I already mention in my question, on their webpage. However, I found that many companies are use Artificial Intelligence (AI) in Cost estimation, Project auditing etc which is related to me. Can I tell them benefits of utilizing AI in their company works?

Comment: (Hopefully you've searched more than just their webpage.) Sure, you can tell them the benefits, though you should note that they are a consulting company, which means they engage with clients and give clients advice. They are probably already aware of the benefits, but looking to improve their capability.